# Java xml Transformer to escape &

Tags: java, xml, ampersand, transformer-model

I am having a problem with `javax.xml.transform.Transformer`.

I am trying to create a XML document and one of the attributes is HTTP link which contains `&` for query. After I've invoked the `transform()` method, all the `&` characters become `&amp;`.

So is there any way that I can configure Transformer not to convert `&` to `&amp;`? Thanks in advance.

Edit

---

In the xml document that I am trying to create, one of the attributes is a http link with query string. So what I would like to have as a result is something like

```
<Notification url="http://www.xyz.com/notify.jsp?param1=123&param2=345/>
```

But I am getting now is

```
<Notification url="http://www.xyz.com/notify.jsp?param1=123&amp;param2=345/>
```

Because I have to transform the xml document into a String and send it over socket. So I do not want `&` converted to `&amp;` as final result.

Comment: **...that I configure Transformer not to convert '&' to '&'** - you mean '&' to '&amp;'? or do you want something other than '&' to appear?

Comment: Sorry anirvan, I forgot to check after posted. Yes, I don't want '&' to be converted to '& amp;'. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After I've invoked transform method, all the `&` characters become `&amp;`

That's exactly what *has to* happen.

What makes you assume that `<div>A &amp; B</div>` is correct XML/HTML and something like `<div title="A &amp; B" />` is not?

The `&` has to be escaped *absolutely everywhere*, that includes attribute values, such as `href`.

Comment: Hi Tomalak. As I mentioned in my question, I need to set a http link as an attribute in the xml document. Then I need to transform it to a String and send it over a socket. So I need to have something like url://www.xyz.com/test.html?param1=123&param2=234 but not with &amp;.

Comment: @KHein: I'm not entirely sure what you are doing. But your question can lead to no other conclusion than that you are doing it wrong. You should expand your question with samples of the XML and the XSLT.

Comment: @Tomalak, I tried to elaborate a bit more in my question. Please let me know if it is still ambiguous.

Comment: @KHein: No, it's not ambiguous anymore, but you are still in error. ;-) `<Notification url="http://www.xyz.com/notify.jsp?param1=123&param2=345" />` is not well-formed XML. You can't have it, because it's wrong. And I'm pretty sure you don't want it, either. So what makes you think that it would not work with `&amp;`?

Comment: @Tomalak,Yes you are right. I was trying to do something wrong. It does work with &amp;. Thanks a lot!